# How to fetch only one object instead of an array while using scopes on included models in sequelize

Tags: sequelize.js

I want to fetch only a single object instead of an array while using scopes on included model

I have defined the limit to be 1 on the scope login of the included model, although I can understand this doesn't makes sense and will not help

This is my code of the included Orders model

```
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  var Order = sequelize.define('Order', {
    oid: {
      type: DataTypes.BIGINT.UNSIGNED,
      primaryKey: true,
      allowNull: false,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    ... other attributes
  }, {
      scopes: {
        latest: {
          limit: 1,
          order: [
            ['oid', 'DESC'],
          ]
        }
      }
    }, {
      indexes: [{
        fields: ['oid']
      }]
    })

  return Order
}
```

And I am trying to fetch the latest order on the Users model like this

```
const user = await models.User.findById(req.user.uEmail, {
    include: [
      models.Order.scope('latest'),
    ]
  });
```

I am expecting the Orders to be an object instead of an array with just one object in it

Answer (score 0):

You need one-to-one relation, when defining user order relation use `hasOne` or `belongsTo` methods:

```
User.hasOne(Order, { as: 'order' });
```

See examples [here](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#hasone).
Difference between `hasOne` and `belongsTo` [docs](https://sequelize.org/master/manual/associations.html#difference-between-hasone-and-belongsto).

Comment: Thanks for the update. I totally forgot to mention I already have a relationship defined on Orders model which references User. Your suggestion will result in cyclic dependency. I will update the original question to include the relationship.